# Add C:\Python27\Scripts to path in Windows 8

Tags: python, windows-8, path, pip

I want to add `C:\Python27\Scripts` to the `path` in `Windows 8`. I have here now:

```
...;C:\Python27\Scripts\
```

In the directory is a pip.exe and I can run pip when I am in this directory in the CMD. But when I am only in the C:-directory, I can't run pip because this command is unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[If you updated](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) the `%PATH%`, for you to access the files in the new locations that it points to, you need to initialize a new shell.

Once you've done that `pip.exe` (or simply, `pip`) should work.

In this case your `%PATH%` should be (or contain) `...;C:\Python27\Scripts\;C:\Python27\;..` for `pip` and for `python` to work in `cmd`.